# JMSSerialerBundle deserialize relation

Tags: jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have entities that are related I would like to serialize entity with all its relations, the serialization works fine (I think) for example, I save this json.

```
{  
  "relation_one":1,
  "relation_two":1,
  "relation_three":1,
  "other_integer_data":2996,
  "other_integer_data2":1174
}
```

Latter i try to deserialize and I get only

```
{  
  "other_integer_data":2996,
  "other_integer_data2":1174
}
```

The properties which indicate relation are not mapped. What I need to do to get properly mapped object after deserialization.

My entity code:

```
/**
 * @var RelationOne
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RelationOne", inversedBy="entity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="relation_one_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="RESTRICT")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $relationOne;

/**
 * @var RelationTwo
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RelationTwo", inversedBy="entity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="relation_two_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="RESTRICT")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $relationTwo;

/**
 * @var RelationThree
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RelationThree", inversedBy="entity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="relation_three_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="RESTRICT")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $relationThree;



/**
 * @JMS\VirtualProperty
 * @JMS\SerializedName("relation_one")
 * @return integer
 */
public function getVirtualRelationOne()
{
    if ($this->relationOne) {
        return $this->relationOne->getId();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * @JMS\VirtualProperty
 * @JMS\SerializedName("relation_two")
 * @return integer
 */
public function getVirtualRelationTwo()
{
    if ($this->relationOne) {
        return $this->relationOne->getId();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * @JMS\VirtualProperty
 * @JMS\SerializedName("relation_three")
 * @return integer
 */
public function getVirtualRelationThree()
{
    if ($this->relationThree) {
        return $this->relationThree->getId();
    }

    return null;
}
```

**EDIT**
After some testing I found out that those relation id were set only because of virtual methods, and without them they don't event get serialized, so the modified question would be how to properly serialize and deserialize entities with relations.